# Why am I getting odd errors on applying dataframe lambda?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe where I am trying to create a new column based on applying a lambda to two existing columns. The dataframe uses a datetimeindex and each column is either float or int and there are no missing or null values:

```
closeunadj  qtr_timedelta
date        
2021-05-18  128.75  107
2021-05-19  130.21  108
2021-05-20  132.15  109
2021-05-21  132.30  110
2021-05-24  133.34  113

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1021 entries, 2017-05-01 to 2021-05-24
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   closeunadj     1021 non-null   float64
 1   qtr_timedelta  1021 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 63.9 KB
```

The lambda calculates a simple shifted return on the first column using a changing shift count value from the second column.

```
final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge[['closeunadj',
                                       'qtr_timedelta']].apply(lambda x: x['closeunadj'] / x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) - 1)
```

However, I get the following errors (in traceback order) which don’t make sense to me since the dataframe values are either datetimeindex, float, or int (as outlined above). ‘closeunadj’ is float64, index is datetimeindex, and there are no str objects.

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
KeyError: 'closeunadj'
ParserError: Unknown string format: closeunadj
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
KeyError: ‘closeunadj'
```

I have tried recasting the columns to float and int, recasting the datetimeindex, recreating the dataframe and using a different lambda syntax, all to no avail.  Any help or fix greatly appreciated!

This is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4410             try:
-> 4411                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
   4412             except IndexError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas/_libs/util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    650         try:
--> 651             value = Index.get_value(self, series, key)
    652         except KeyError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4418                 else:
-> 4419                     raise e1
   4420             except Exception:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine._date_check_type()

KeyError: 'closeunadj'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_str_to_tsobject()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1373     else:
-> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1375 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    648         if res is None:
--> 649             raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
    650 

ParserError: Unknown string format: closeunadj

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    659             try:
--> 660                 return self.get_value_maybe_box(series, key)
    661             except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_value_maybe_box(self, series, key)
    674         elif not isinstance(key, Timestamp):
--> 675             key = Timestamp(key)
    676         values = self._engine.get_value(com.values_from_object(series), key, tz=self.tz)

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_str_to_tsobject()

ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-ac0ccaa452bc> in <module>
      1 # Use close price change from date of last results
----> 2 final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge[['closeunadj',
      3                                        'qtr_timedelta']].apply(lambda x : x['closeunadj'] / x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) - 1)
      4 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879 
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    293 
    294             try:
--> 295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
    296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )

pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

<ipython-input-55-ac0ccaa452bc> in <lambda>(x)
      1 # Use close price change from date of last results
      2 final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge[['closeunadj',
----> 3                                        'qtr_timedelta']].apply(lambda x : x['closeunadj'] / x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) - 1)
      4 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    660                 return self.get_value_maybe_box(series, key)
    661             except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError):
--> 662                 raise KeyError(key)
    663         else:
    664             return com.maybe_box(self, value, series, key)

KeyError: 'closeunadj'
```

Comment: try passing `axis=1` in `apply()` method....i.e:`final_merge[['closeunadj','qtr_timedelta']].apply(lambda x: x['closeunadj'] / x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) - 1,axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks. Still get an error. But this time just AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'

Comment: can you post your expected output from your current given dataframe?

Comment: I have now discoverd why the lambda doesn't work - but still not how to fix it. Since apply() is working row by row, the x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) is trying to shift on a single value (not the whole series as I was expecting). Thus it can't execute the shift. So I need to find a way to have the shift() access the whole x['closeunadj'] series.

Comment: However, if I try to use x.loc[:,'closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) in the denominator I just get "IndexingError: Too many indexers".

Comment: This question has been answered creating a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705515/how-to-use-shift-within-apply-in-dataframe-and-still-access-full-series

Comment: sounds good **:)**