# How to use shift() within apply() in dataframe and still access full series?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, shift

I have a dataframe where I am trying to create a new column based on applying a lambda to two columns.

```
closeunadj  qtr_timedelta
date        
2021-05-18  128.75  107
2021-05-19  130.21  108
2021-05-20  132.15  109
2021-05-21  132.30  110
2021-05-24  133.34  113

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1021 entries, 2017-05-01 to 2021-05-24
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   closeunadj     1021 non-null   float64
 1   qtr_timedelta  1021 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 63.9 KB
```

The lambda is supposed to be calculating a simple shifted return on the first column using a changing shift count value from the second column.

```
final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge[['closeunadj',
                                       'qtr_timedelta']].apply(lambda x : x['closeunadj'] / x['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']) - 1, axis=1)
```

However, because the apply() is running row by row I cannot get shift() to access the the full ‘closeunadj’ series to calculate the actual shift(). Thus I get a “AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute ‘shift’"

If I change the denominator to

```
x.loc[:,’closeunadj’].shift(x[‘qtr_timedelta’])
```

to try to get shift() to access the whole series I get “IndexingError: Too many indexers”

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: how many different values in the column qtr_timedelta you have, what is the result of `final_merge['qtr_timedelta '].nunique()`?

Comment: Thanks. 107 unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the full series `final_merge['closeunadj']` for the `shift` in the `apply`, then use `loc` with `x.name` (that is the index of the current row) to get the right value. Not sure it is the most efficient but because your dataframe is about 1K rows, should be fine

```
final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = (
    final_merge[['closeunadj', 'qtr_timedelta']]
      .apply(lambda x : x['closeunadj'] / final_merge['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']).loc[x.name] - 1, 
             axis=1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggeston, but I get the following error with that code "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method"

Comment: I can get the code to run without an error using:  final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge.apply(lambda x: x['closeunadj'] / final_merge.loc[:,'closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']), axis=1) but all values are returned as NaNs which is obviously still not correct.

Comment: @user11079386 hmm if I use your method, I get only nan in the column. maybe add the result of `final_merge[['closeunadj', 'qtr_timedelta']].head(5).to_dict()` in your question to see what I did wrong when trying to reproduce your data

Comment: Yes. It is messing a way to get the correct index value from the shifted series. I would expect final_merge['qtr_gwth'] = final_merge.apply(lambda x: x['closeunadj'] / final_merge['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']).loc[x['closeunadj']], axis=1) would work, but I get the error "TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [55.8] of <class 'float'>" So stil stuck.

Comment: Ben.T not sure if it will make a difference but what pandas version are you running, where your answer worked without the"TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method"?

Comment: @user11079386 yes with the toy data I created similar to what yours looks like, the solution provided works for me. As I said, maybe I don't exactly have the same datatype. It could be also a duplicate in the index or as you suggested a version issue, I'm running on 1.1.1, which makes me realize I should update it :p

Comment: Ben.T I am running 1.0.5 so I will also look to udpate and see if I can get your answer to work. Having looked more into apply() and shift() functions, I do feel your answer should work, but I continue to get the same error "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method". I also get it even if just create the same new 'toy data' dataframe. Really frustrating. I have been stuck on this one issue for days now.

Comment: Finally got it to work! I have no idea why it was failing before, but a very slight variation on your answer finally worked. final_merge['qtr_growth'] = final_merge.apply(lambda x: x['closeunadj'] / final_merge['closeunadj'].shift(x['qtr_timedelta']).loc[x.name] - 1, axis=1). Many thanks Ben.T!

Comment: @user11079386 weird that this change it works and not in the original! anyway, glad it works :)